# Uncaught TypeError: (o.contentType || "").indexOf is not a function

Tags: jquery, formularios

Al intentar enviar un formulario, me salta este error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

jQuery analiza el formulario. Si tiene un archivo lo adjunta y si no serializa las variables.

Aquí el código:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("body").on("submit", "form", function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();

    var type = "POST";
    var url = $(this).prop("action");
    var cache = false;
    var contentType = true;
    var processData = true;

    if (this.files.length) {
        var data = new FormData(this);
        contentType = false;
        processData = false;
    } else {
    var data = $(this).serialize();
    }
    $.ajax({
       url: url,
      data: data,
      type: type,
      cache: cache,
      contentType: contentType,
        processData: processData
    }).done(function(data) {
    $(".section").html(data);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He modificado el código porque las imágenes no se cargaban y éste es el código definitivo.

Muchas gracias a [@OscarGarcia](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/18608/oscargarcia) sin él no lo hubiese conseguido.

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
$("body").on("submit", "form", function(event) {
            event.stopPropagation();
         event.preventDefault();  

         var type = "POST";  
           var url = $(this, "form").prop("action");  
           var cache = false;
            var contentType = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
            var processData = true;     

         if(event.target.files) {           
            var data = new FormData(this);
            contentType = false;
                processData = false;
            } 
            else {
                var data = $(this).serialize();
            }

            $.ajax({
            url: url,
              data: data,
              type: type,
              cache: cache,
              contentType: contentType,
              processData: processData
            })
            .done(function(data) {
                $(".section").html(data);
            }); 
        });
 });
```

Comment: Hola @Isaac Palacio. La comunidad no funciona de esta manera. Este código debería ir en una edición de tu pregunta si quieres dejar la solución que adoptaste, y si mi respuesta fue la que te solucionó o ayudó a solucionar tu problema, marcarla como correcta. Comprende que invertí mucho tiempo redactando, investigando tu problema, intercambiando mensajes, buscando la solución, etc. Yo voté positivo tu pregunta por considerarla relevante para otros usuarios (te di 5 de reputación por ello).

Comment: Si marcas como respuesta correcta la tuya propia no solo no conseguirás reputación por ello, si no que además me has restado 15 puntos de reputación como agradecimiento por todo mi esfuerzo.

Comment: No era ni es mi intención restarte puntos, ni sabía que marcando mi respuesta como buena te resta a ti, cosa que veo ridícula, si marco mi respuesta como correcta, no es por dame puntos, de hecho ni siquiera me fijo en la reputación, solo en quien me puede ayudar o no, si pongo la solución aparte sin modificar la pregunta es por coherencia, si alguien viene detrás mio y ve la pregunta mía corregida no sabrá que problema tuve ¿No es más coherente exponer el problema y ver aparte la solución y no entrar y ver directamente la solución sin saber que paso?

Comment: Es lo que hago yo cuando entro en webs similares, me fijo en las respuestas que están marcadas en verde, no miro la pregunta, porque asumo que esta mal, pero me sirve para ver si tiene mi mismo problema. Por eso marque mi respuesta como correcta indicando que fue gracias a ti, porque tu respuesta sin modificación no es valida y no me parece correcto marcarla como correcta pero te lo agradezco marcándola como respuesta útil e indicándolo en la respuesta como o he hecho.

Comment: Si te fijas en webs similares el autor no se responde a sí mismo tras que otra persona le haya solucionado el problema y se asigna la respuesta correcta. La explicación, los datos técnicos, las alternativas, están en la respuesta que debe marcarse como buena y las actualizaciones del autor de la pregunta (incluso la resolución si así lo desea) se mantiene en la pregunta. Me restaste reputación porque previamente mi respuesta la marcaste como correcta, eso me otorga 15 puntos, al cambiar a la tuya me quitan esos 15 puntos.

Comment: Ahora entiendo lo de los 15 puntos, pero vuelvo a decir, tu respuesta me guió, no fue la solución la solución la encontré gracias a tu ayuda sí, pero también gracias a Google y gracias a ir haciendo pruebas cambiando y adaptando el código, no veo licito marcar tu respuesta como la solución cuando no lo fue.

Comment: Es más, si modificas tu respuesta poniendo el código valido, para mi pregunta, no tengo ningún problema en borrar mi respuesta y dar la tuya como buena, como ya te dije, para mi la reputación es lo de menos, pero lo que no puedo hacer es marcar un código que no funciona (en mi caso) como bueno.

Comment: Si no mandas un archivo (si no seleccionas uno al menos) la condición `event.target.files` siempre será cierta porque existe (y no compruebas cuántos archivos hay), por lo que ocultas la asignación `processData = true` que es la que te provocaba el fallo de la pregunta asignando `processData = false` **SIEMPRE**. En mi código lo hace de manera correcta (con la comprobación `this['files[]'].files.length`, comprobando el número de archivos a enviar).

Comment: Así que "tu solución" sólo enmascara el problema impidiendo que se mande el `processData = true` que provoca el error `Uncaught TypeError: (o.contentType || “”).indexOf is not a function`.

Answer (score 0):

Posiblemente el error se deba a que para el `contentType: contentType` estás usando un `booleano` y espera un `string`, de ahí el `indexOf`.

Prueba a quitar esa propiedad para que haga uso del valor por defecto y así ya no debería fallar.

Además, no es buena práctica nombrar las variables de los valores con el mismo nombre que la propiedad, esto te puede dar bastantes quebraderos de cabeza (o al menos entrecomillar los nombres de las propiedades).

Answer (score 0):

Estás haciendo un mal uso accidental de `contentType: true`. Deberías omitir esa línea y dejar:

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  data: data,
  type: type,
  cache: cache,
  processData: processData
}).done(function(data) {
  $(".section").html(data);
});
```

Tal y como pone la [documentación de `jQuery.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) el valor de `contentType` puede ser `Boolean` o `String`, pero lo que no deja bien claro es que en caso de ser `Boolean` sólo puede valer `false`:

> When sending data to the server, use this content type. Default is
>   "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8", which is fine for
>   most cases. If you explicitly pass in a content-type to $.ajax(), then
>   it is always sent to the server (even if no data is sent). As of
>   jQuery 1.6 you can pass false to tell jQuery to not set any content
>   type header.

En castellano:

> Cuando se envían datos al servidor, usar este tipo de contenido. Por
>   defecto es "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8", que está
>   bien en la mayoría de casos. Si especificas explícitamente un
>   `content-type` a `$.ajax()`, entonces es siempre enviado al servidor
>   (incluso cuando no se envían datos). **A partir de `jQuery 1.6` puedes
>   pasar `false` para no enviar ninguna cabecera `content type`**.

Pero han olvidado detallar que si pasas un `true` se [provoca un error en esta línea](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax.js#L618):

```
( s.contentType || "" ).indexOf( "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" ) === 0
```

Ya que no han tenido en cuenta que en el caso de que `s.contentType` valga `true` no se usará `""` como entrada al `indexOf` siguiente, si no el propio valor `true` que no dispone de método `indexOf` por ser un tipo de dato primitivo.

Realizando algunas modificaciones en tu código he conseguido echar a andar tu aplicación:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("body").on("submit", "form", function(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        event.preventDefault();

        var type = "post";
        var url = $(this).prop("action");
        /* Cuando mandamos sólo texto (sin archivos)
             configuramos estos valores */
        var contentType = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
        var processData = true;

        /* Para que PHP reciba todos los archivos hay que definir
             el <input> con corchetes, de modo que aquí tenemos que
             indicarlo igual */
        if (this['files[]'].files.length) {
            var data = new FormData(this);
            /* En este caso sí que hay que cambiar estos parámetros,
                 en particular contentType=false provoca una cabecera HTTP
                 'multipart/form-data; boundary=----...' */
            contentType = false;
            processData = false;
        } else {
            var data = $(this).serialize();
        }
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            data: data,
            type: type,
            contentType: contentType,
            processData: processData
        }).done(function(data) {
            $(".section").html(data);
        });
    });
});
</script>
<form id="form" action="formulario.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Pon algo..." name="campo" /><br />
    <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar formulario" />
</form>
<pre class="section"></pre>
```

Comment: Hola @OscarGarcia , Tenía entendido que el contentType = false; era necesario para enviar archivos a traves del formulario igualmente, al quitar el contentType, se envía el formulario, pero sin datos por post, porque el PHP no me detecta datos por POST y me recarga el formulario.

Comment: ¿Puedes publicar el código del PHP y el formulario HTML? Probablemente algo está mal, pero no creo que esté en la llamada `$.ajax`, estará antes (JS/HTML) o después (PHP).

Comment: ¿Y si pruebas a ponerlo a `false` en vez de `true` para ver si sin cabecera funciona? ¿Qué es lo que quieres subir? Con el código HTML del formulario puedo hacerme una idea y puedo reproducir el problema.

Comment: Ya tengo el error!! Dame unos minutos para editar mi respuesta :D

Comment: PD: Por un lado `this.files.length` impedía que se detectara cuando tenías archivos, sería `this.files.files.length`. Ahora estoy viendo la parte de PHP para recoger los archivos correctamente.

Comment: Espero que te funcione con estas modificaciones :) Hice mis pruebas aquí: https://gist.github.com/ojgarciab/f1ecb3c8e0b8291f2be640a7da69138b

Comment: Gracias @oscargarcia estuve desconectado este finde, ahora pruebo lo que me dices y si no funciona amplio información.

Comment: Hola por lo que veo este código es para subir varios archivos, yo solo quiero subir uno, no varios, en principio el código es para que funciones sobre varios formularios, que pueden o no tener un `input type="file"` lo que si es seguro es que solo quiero que puedan subir solo un archivo, no varios. Ahora me doy cuenta de que simplemente al enviar no hace nada. Con PHP lo único que hago es comprobar si se ha enviado el submit `if($_POST['submit']) {`

Comment: Esa comprobación por qué la haces? No es válida, no hay ningún campo llamado "submit" en el formulario.

Comment: Es una manera de comprobar por PHP que se han enviado datos por POST

Comment: No, es una manera de comprobar que se ha enviado un campo llamado `submit` mediante el método `post`. Para comprobar eso hay que mirar el contenido de `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']`.

Comment: Si quieres comprobar que cierto campo del formulario ha sido enviado, como en mi caso el `input` con `name="campo"`, se usaría `isset($_POST['campo'])`. Pero el campo `sumbit` no existe si no hay un campo en el formulario con `name="submit"` o lo defines en la llamada XHR.

Comment: Si, tienes razón, no lo estaba utilizando bien ahora parece que el código funciona, tengo un problema con los checkboxs, pero a ver si lo soluciono.

Comment: ¿Qué problema tienes? Si quieres escribe una nueva pregunta y me pones aquí en enlace para que la mire lo antes que pueda.